# Can't run javaFX

Tags: javafx

It worked just fine and then suddenly i got this error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/21122690.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.png.PNGImageLoader2.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.loadAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.loadImage(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.loadImage(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/32359153.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/11567059.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/4247839.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
Exception running application application.Main
```

And it points me to my main class

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import connection.Conexiune;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {


            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
                    "/application/MyView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(
                    getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.setTitle("StarMap v7.5");


            primaryStage.show();
            setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);

            Conexiune.createConnection();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

more exactly this line i don't know why because it worked fine until now all i did is add another imageview to the interface using scene builder

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/MyView.fxml"));
```

can anyone please help me?

this is my FXML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="aPane" centerShape="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" scaleShape="false" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MyController">
   <effect>
      <Blend />
   </effect>
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="secPane" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <ComboBox fx:id="ora" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="217.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" promptText="Selectati ora" visible="false" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="data" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="127.0" promptText="Selectati data" />
            <Pane fx:id="imgPaneIanuarie" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="692.0" prefWidth="1066.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" visible="false">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="sMap" fitHeight="692.0" fitWidth="1066.0" layoutX="-1.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                  <ImageView fx:id="Sirius" fitHeight="16.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="335.0" layoutY="433.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoSirius" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredSirius" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/sirius.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Procyon" fitHeight="12.0" fitWidth="11.0" layoutX="284.0" layoutY="319.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoProcyon" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredProcyon" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/procyon.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Beetlegeuse" fitHeight="13.0" fitWidth="13.0" layoutX="402.0" layoutY="319.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoBetelgeuse" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredBeetlegeuse" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/beetlegeuse.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Rigel" fitHeight="12.0" fitWidth="13.0" layoutX="450.0" layoutY="398.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoRigel" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredRigel" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/rigel.png" />
                     </image></ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Capella" fitHeight="18.0" fitWidth="16.0" layoutX="449.0" layoutY="126.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoCapella" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredCapella" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/capella.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Aldebaran" fitHeight="9.0" fitWidth="10.0" layoutX="497.0" layoutY="281.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoAldebaran" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredAldebaran" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/aldebaran.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Polux" fitHeight="10.0" fitWidth="11.0" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="213.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoPollux" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredPolux" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/polux.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Castor" fitHeight="7.0" fitWidth="6.0" layoutX="314.0" layoutY="199.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoCastor" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredCastor" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/castor.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Regulus" fitHeight="8.0" fitWidth="8.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="229.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoRegulus" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredRegulus" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/regulus.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="Mirphak" fitHeight="10.0" fitWidth="10.0" layoutX="579.0" layoutY="54.0" onMouseClicked="#getInfoMirfak" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredMirphak" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/mirphak.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label layoutX="511.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="35.0" text=" N" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textFill="#fc0f0f">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="508.0" layoutY="643.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="35.0" text="  S" textFill="#fc0f0f">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="1017.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="35.0" text=" W" textFill="#fc0f0f">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="329.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="35.0" text="  E" textFill="#fc0f0f">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="debug" fitHeight="5.0" fitWidth="5.0" layoutX="487.0" layoutY="438.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/red.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos1" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="1027.0" layoutY="653.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos2" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="964.0" layoutY="658.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos3" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="1010.0" layoutY="636.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos4" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="794.0" layoutY="494.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos5" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="419.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos6" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="434.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nodePos7" disable="true" fitHeight="15.0" fitWidth="15.0" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="434.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/halo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoSirius" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="578.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/blueStar.gif" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameSirius" contentDisplay="CENTER" disable="true" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="556.0" lineSpacing="5.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Sirius" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoBetlegeuse" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="592.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/redStar.gif" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameBetelgeuse" disable="true" layoutX="114.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Betlegeuse" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoMirfak" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="213.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/mirphakStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameMirfak" disable="true" layoutX="219.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Mirfak" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoProcyon" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/mirphakStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameProcyon" disable="true" layoutX="284.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Procyon" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="sNamePolux" disable="true" layoutX="371.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Pollux" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoPolux" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="372.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/poluxStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoCapella" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="547.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/capellaStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameCapella" disable="true" layoutX="546.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Capella" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameRegulus" disable="true" layoutX="628.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Regulus" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoRegulus" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="629.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/regulusStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoAldebaran" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="719.0" layoutY="578.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/aldebaranstar.gif" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameAldebaran" disable="true" layoutX="719.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Aldebaran" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoRigel" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="838.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/rigeStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="sNameRigel" disable="true" layoutX="837.0" layoutY="556.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Rigel" textFill="WHITE" underline="true" visible="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fx:id="infoCastor" disable="true" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="952.0" layoutY="604.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../Img/castorStar.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>


                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children></Pane>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: The cause of the error is `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. May the size of the image that you are trying to load is the culprit, but I am not sure. Can you post the FXML ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha 1 sec please

Comment: @ItachiUchiha thing is that i cant show you all of my FXML because it is too long so i posted kinda half of it but the rest is the same mostly labels and image views

Comment: @ItachiUchiha and the image i use are not anything that i havent used untill now when the program was working

Comment: @ItachiUchiha so asuming it is too long for my FXML how do i create more heap space?

Comment: You have too many images getting loaded into the memory and therefore the heap space error. You can increase the heap space by passing a VM argument -`Xmx1024m`. This will assign 1GB  of space to the JVM